# Estimating error on calculations using decimals

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding-error

We're currently using System.Decimals to represent numbers in a .NET application we're developing. I know that decimals are design to minimize errors due to rounding, but I also know that certain numbers, 1/3 for example, cannot be represented as a decimal so some calculations will have small rounding error. I believe the magnitude of this error will be very small and insignificant, however a colleague disagrees. I would therefore like to be able to estimate the order of magnitude of the error due to rounding in our app. Say, for example, we are calculating a running total of “deals” and will do about 10,000 “deals” per day and there are about 5-10 decimal operations (add, sub, div, mul etc.) to calculate the running total new running total for each deal received, what would be the order of magnate of round error? An answer with a procedure for calculating this would also be nice, so I can learn how to do this for myself in the future.

Comment: Decimal can represent upto 28 decimal places - it is suitable for monetary operations.
If you are smart about your operations you would limit division and multiplication or implement counter measures so as to eliminate division/multiplication inaccuracy (using rounding + subtracting or other methods).
Direct monetary values won't have many decimal spaces so adding/subtracting is safe. Some crazy divisions (if cumulative) will result in losses no matter how wide a datatype is used (if you do not use counter-measures).

Comment: One thing I've never been sure of, I understand that a decimal can represent upto 28 decimal places, but does this change as the maginuted of the decimal increases? i.e. can a decimal that holds a value of a million still have a 28 places after the decimal point?

Comment: Yes - decimal is fixed point, so the accuracy is the same for large and small numbers. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx

Comment: On reading the docs more closely I see it is a floating point, therefore a number with a greater maginute does not have as many decimal places available as a smaller one.

Comment: Huh? You point to says its floating point, no?: "A decimal number is a floating-point value that consists of a sign, a numeric value where each digit in the value ranges from 0 to 9, and a scaling factor that indicates the position of a floating decimal point that separates the integral and fractional parts of the numeric value."

Comment: Bah, you're right; I can't read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) goes into detail on estimating the error in the result of a sequence of floating point operations, given the precision of the floating point type. I haven't tried this on any practical program, though, so I'd be interested to know if it's feasible.

Comment: Would have been nice if someone could have translated it into words of one syllable for me, but I guess this is the correct answer.