# Estimate error in floating point calculations

Tags: .net, floating-point, double

One important property of IEEE floating-point math that rounding causes "errors" in calculations due to the limited number of bits and the base-2 format.

E.g. in C#:

```
(Math.PI * 1e20 / 1e20) == Math.PI; // false
```

Is there a way to determine the magnitude of the error of those operations? .NET exposes the [`Double.Epsilon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.epsilon.aspx) field that give the smallest significant value greater than zero, but that's not relevant for comparing non-zero numbers.

EDIT: I'm not asking for a way to *exactly* compute the error, I'm just trying to find a way to estimate its magnitude.

For example (again, in C#):

```
(1e20 + 1e3) == 1e20; // true
(1e20 + 1e4) == 1e20; // false
```

So the error of the operation `1e20 + X` appears to be approximately 1e3, which makes sense because `doubles` have up to 17 digits of decimal precision.

Comment: I suppose you should just calculate the error estimation based on your calculations. You may find some helpful information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166851/estimating-error-on-calculations-using-decimals.

Comment: The error is discrete and cumulative and it may or may not occur for each calculation.  To predict or calculate the exact error for every calculation would be extremely time consuming (you would have to do a software calculation to another arbitrary precision to do this) but it can be done.  You could also do this with something like delphi which supports 80-bit extended precision floats.

Comment: @Lucas: what do you mean "calculate the error estimation based on your calculations"?

Comment: @Henry: I meant you can calculate the error using information about how error changes when you do specific calculations in your algorithm (i.e. when you have a value of *x* and you know that error of *x* is *0.1* and you want to calculate *10 * x*, error  of the result is *10 * 0.1 = 1*). Now in your updated question I see you just want get an approximate value of it, but I suppose just trying to calculate it can be considered.

Comment: @Lucas: I'm talking about rounding errors in the IEEE floating point spec, not experimental measurement errors. E.g. in my "EDIT" section, all of those numbers are exactly represented by IEEE doubles, but there's still an error in the addition calculation done by the computer.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the machine epsilon (which you can calculate) not the smallest (denorm) positive number: see  http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/08/c-math-gotchas/ for the bizarre naming convention.

Once you have the machine epsilon, you know (from the IEEE standard) that any basic algebraic operation *, +, /, -, has a relative error of at most epsilon, i.e. x flop y = (x op y)(1+delta) where:

- flop is the floating point operation, e.g. a floating-point add
- op is the corresponding operation in real arithmetic
- delta is the relative roundoff error and is bounded by |delta| <= epsilon

Comment: this is not true. Especially division can be less accurate.